# Calling A Tool From Another Form to Another?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdi, toolbox

im working on a code-editor(winforms) and Im just wondering if its possible to call a specific box from a form to another?

sample for this set of codes:

```
int line = 1 + richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());
int column = 1 + richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
label1.Text = "line: " + line.ToString() + ", column: " + column.ToString();
```

***code above was inside a timer which calls the count of line and column in a richtextbox like in lower rightpart of actual code editor .

now im just wondering if its possible to call the label that displays to the main form and will display to another but will still run .

like in mainform theres the code for richtextbox and on other form it should have the code of label that connects to the mainform .

> my question is it possible to call a tool function from another form
>   to another?

hope you could help me, really in need and thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm 99% sure there is a duplicate question here, but the short answer would be to use an event model and subscribe to that event

Comment: @Shimmy its winforms sir i include it in my question :/

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a reference to that form toolbox, just expose that `Label`/`TextBox` or whatever you want to change via a public property and set it from your context.

```
public class ToolBox : ToolBoxBase
{
   public CustomLabel
   {
      get
      {
         return label1.Text;
      }
      set
      {
         label1.Text = value;
      }
   }
}

private ToolBox toolbox;
void ShowToolBox()
{
   InitToolBox();
   toolbox.CustomLabel = "New label";
}
```

As I'm not even sure what technology the question refers to I added a poor pseudo example to get you the idea. The `InitToolBox` method initializes the toolbox and displays it, and sets the field `toolbox` with a reference to it.

If the other form runs on another thread, then you'll have to invoke the label setter asynchronously. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/661706/75500) question for more instructions.

Comment: And from what you seem to be describing there the easiest way to have a reference, as well as being a good logical construct for the two forms, is to have one form be the MDIParent of the other form.

Comment: @Shimmy even two forms are not mdi's?

Comment: @Elegiac yes as long as you have a reference to it and it runs in the same thread. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Shimmy ok sir ill try to do it and make some logic .w8

Comment: @Elegiac really it's not complicated, just copy the code above to your tooltip class and you're done. Good luck! Please don't forget to vote / accept answer if this post helped.

Comment: @Shimmy, sir the ToolBox was missing :/ how to add toolbox in my form?

Comment: Create a field in your form then set that field with the toolbox.

Comment: lol i thought toolbox was a reference but i think its the container of all tools that your referring . sorry sir i dont have anydesigner in my form tools are called by codes only . but still +1 for the help .

Comment: Then you can have a field that holds a reference to the label :)

Comment: @Shimmy sir im thinking if i can use the using namespace; method? sample for mainform namespace (name of otherform); then i can call all tools from main is that possible?